# Why is my async method still blocking tornado?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I'm still new to tornado's async programming.  So I'm not 100% certain I did this the right way.

Here is the script i'm trying to run async

```
import locale
import logging

from tornado.gen import Task, Return, coroutine

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import tz
from mongo import db

@coroutine
def table():
  response = yield Task(driver)
  raise Return(response)

@coroutine
def driver():
  try:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
  except:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')

  from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
  to_zone = tz.gettz('America/New_York')
  utc = datetime.utcnow()
  utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
  current_date = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
  start_at = current_date + timedelta(days=-2)
  end_at = current_date + timedelta(days=-1)

  start_date = start_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  start_day = start_at.strftime("%a")
  end_date = end_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  end_day = end_at.strftime("%a")

  year = end_at.strftime("%Y")
  prev_year = year
  month = end_at.strftime("%m")
  prev_month = int(month) - 1
  if prev_month < 1:
    prev_month = "12"
    prev_year = str(int(prev_year) - 1)
  else:
    if prev_month < 10:
      prev_month = "0%s" % prev_month
    prev_month = str(prev_month)

  dates = {start_date:{}}
  while start_at < end_at:
    end_slot = start_at + timedelta(days=1)
    start_at += timedelta(days=1)
    dates[end_slot.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")] = {}

  logging.info('getting sites from db')
  sites = list(db.sites.find())

  revenue_totals = {}
  provider_totals = {}
  rev_providers = {}
  # slugs, tags, name, PLACEMENT, TOTAL_IMPRESSIONS, FILLED_IMPRESSIONS, DEFAULTED_IMPRESSIONS, REVENUE, DATE, NETWORK, CTR, AD_SIZE, LOCATION, CPM
  for date in dates.keys():
    logging.info('retrieving data for {0}'.format(date))
    records = list(db.revenue_data.find({'date': date}))
    logging.info('data recieved, parsing...')
    for record in records:
      for rec in record['records']:
        rec['slugs'] = []
        try:
          rec['REVENUE'] = float(rec['REVENUE'].replace('$','').replace(',',''))
        except:
          rec['REVENUE'] = rec['REVENUE']

        # add to our revenue provider tallies
        if rec['PLACEMENT'].find('l2') > -1 or rec['PLACEMENT'].find('2nd') > -1 or rec['PLACEMENT'].find('second') > -1:
            rec['NETWORK'] = '%s_2nd' % rec['NETWORK']
        if rec['NETWORK'].lower() in rev_providers.keys():
          if date in rev_providers[rec['NETWORK'].lower()].keys():
            if float(rec['REVENUE']) > 0.0:
              rev_providers[rec['NETWORK'].lower()][date]['revenue'] += rec['REVENUE']
              rev_providers[rec['NETWORK'].lower()][date]['count'] += 1
          else:
            if float(rec['REVENUE']) > 0.0:
              rev_providers[rec['NETWORK'].lower()][date] = {'revenue':rec['REVENUE'],'count':1}
        else:
          if float(rec['REVENUE']) > 0.0:
            rev_providers[rec['NETWORK'].lower()] = {date:{'revenue':rec['REVENUE'],'count':1}}
        if date in provider_totals:
          if float(rec['REVENUE']) > 0.0:
            provider_totals[date]['revenue'] += rec['REVENUE']
            provider_totals[date]['count'] += 1
        else:
          if float(rec['REVENUE']) > 0.0:
            provider_totals[date] = {'revenue':rec['REVENUE'],'count':1}
        # determine what slugs match this line item
        for site in sites:
          append_slug = False
          if 'reporting' in site.keys():
            for r in site['reporting']:
              if r.strip() != '' and rec['PLACEMENT'].replace(' ','').lower().find(r.strip().lower()) > -1:
                append_slug = True
          if 'prevent_reporting' in site.keys():
            for r in site['prevent_reporting']:
              if r.strip() != '' and rec['PLACEMENT'].replace(' ','').lower().find(r.strip().lower()) > -1:
                append_slug = False
          if append_slug:
            rec['slugs'].append(site['slug'])
            try:
              rec['tags'] = site['tags']
            except:
              rec['tags'] = []
            rec['name'] = site['name']
        if 'name' in rec.keys() and float(rec['REVENUE']) > 0.0:
          # this is a line item we want to keep
          # determine if we have this site for this date yet
          if rec['name'] in dates[date].keys():
            # we have this site for this date; so let's just add this line item to it
            dates[date][rec['name']].append(rec)
          else:
            # we need to add this site for this date
            dates[date][rec['name']] = [rec]
          if date in revenue_totals.keys():
            revenue_totals[date] += float(rec['REVENUE'])
          else:
            revenue_totals[date] = float(rec['REVENUE'])

  mtd_sum = 0.0
  pmtd_sum = 0.0
  rp_html = ''
  rp_html += '<p>%s generated <strong>%s</strong> in revenue.</p>' % (end_date, locale.currency(revenue_totals[end_date], grouping=True))
  rp_html += '<p>%s generated <strong>%s</strong> in revenue.</p>' % (start_date, locale.currency(revenue_totals[start_date], grouping=True))
  rp_html += '<p>The following table shows the breakdown over these two days.</p>'
  rp_html += '<p></p>'
  rp_html += '<table border="1">'
  rp_html += '<tr>'
  rp_html += '<th>NETWORK</th>'
  rp_html += '<th>%s</th>' % start_date
  rp_html += '<th>TAGS</th>'
  rp_html += '<th>%s</th>' % end_date
  rp_html += '<th>TAGS</th>'
  rp_html += '<th>MTD</th>'
  rp_html += '<th>PM</th>'
  rp_html += '</tr>'
  keys = sorted(rev_providers.keys())
  logging.info('creating table')
  for network in keys:
    rp_html += '<tr>'
    rp_html += '<td>%s</td>' % network

    # show the start date details
    try:
      rp_html += '<td align="right">%s</td>' % locale.currency(rev_providers[network][start_date]['revenue'], grouping=True)
      # log in the revenue provider history
      date_bits = start_date.split('-')
      db.revenue_provider_history.update({'network':network, 'date':start_date}, {'network':network,'date':start_date,'revenue':rev_providers[network][start_date]['revenue'],'count':rev_providers[network][start_date]['count'],'day':date_bits[2],'month':date_bits[1],'year':date_bits[0],'day_of_week':start_day}, upsert=True)
    except:
      rp_html += '<td align="right">$0.00</td>'
    try:
      rp_html += '<td align="right">%s</td>' % rev_providers[network][start_date]['count']
    except:
      rp_html += '<td align="right">0</td>'

    # show the end date details
    try:
      rp_html += '<td align="right">%s</td>' % locale.currency(rev_providers[network][end_date]['revenue'], grouping=True)
      # log in the revenue provider history
      date_bits = end_date.split('-')
      db.revenue_provider_history.update({'network':network, 'date':end_date}, {'network':network,'date':end_date,'revenue':rev_providers[network][end_date]['revenue'],'count':rev_providers[network][end_date]['count'],'day':date_bits[2],'month':date_bits[1],'year':date_bits[0],'day_of_week':end_day}, upsert=True)
    except:
      rp_html += '<td align="right">$0.00</td>'
    try:
      rp_html += '<td align="right">%s</td>' % rev_providers[network][end_date]['count']
    except:
      rp_html += '<td align="right">0</td>'

    # get the MTD total
    mtd_results = db.revenue_provider_history.aggregate([
      {'$match':{'network':network,'year':year,'month':month}},
      {'$group':{'_id':{'network':'$network'}, 'total':{'$sum':'$revenue'}}}
    ])
    for res in mtd_results:
      mtd_rec = res
    try:
      rp_html += '<td align="right">%s</td>' % locale.currency(mtd_rec['total'], grouping=True)
      mtd_sum += mtd_rec['total']
    except:
      rp_html += '<td>N/A</td>'

    # get the PMTD total
    mtd_results = db.revenue_provider_history.aggregate([
      {'$match':{'network':network,'year':prev_year,'month':prev_month}},
      {'$group':{'_id':{'network':'$network'}, 'total':{'$sum':'$revenue'}}}
    ])
    for res in mtd_results:
      mtd_rec = res
    try:
      rp_html += '<td align="right">%s</td>' % locale.currency(mtd_rec['total'], grouping=True)
      pmtd_sum += mtd_rec['total']
    except:
      rp_html += '<td>N/A</td>'
    rp_html += '</tr>'
  rp_html += '<tr>'
  rp_html += '<td>&nbsp;</td>'
  rp_html += '<td align="right">%s</td>' % locale.currency(provider_totals[start_date]['revenue'], grouping=True)
  rp_html += '<td align="right">%s</td>' % provider_totals[start_date]['count']
  rp_html += '<td align="right">%s</td>' % locale.currency(provider_totals[end_date]['revenue'], grouping=True)
  rp_html += '<td align="right">%s</td>' % provider_totals[end_date]['count']
  rp_html += '<td align="right">%s</td>' % locale.currency(mtd_sum, grouping=True)
  rp_html += '<td align="right">%s</td>' % locale.currency(pmtd_sum, grouping=True)
  rp_html += '</tr>'
  rp_html += '</table>'

  logging.info("complete")

  return rp_html

def on_timeout():
  logging.info("timeout")
```

Here is the post method/handler

```
#needs work not truely async
class ProviderTable(app.basic.BaseHandler):
  @tornado.web.authenticated
  @coroutine
  def post(self):
    seconds_to_wait = 300
    deadline = time.time() + seconds_to_wait
    IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(deadline, generate_provider_rev_table.on_timeout)

    notes = {}
    logging.info('running table script')
    result = yield generate_provider_rev_table.table()
    if result != '':
      notes['created']   = datetime.utcnow()
      notes['slug']      = ''
      notes['value']     = ''
      notes['logged_by'] = 'systems'
      notes['message']   = 'Revenue table generated at {0}'.format(datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
      audit_notesdb.log_audit_note(notes)
      self.api_response(result)
```

So this is what I'm trying to do.. I want to run the driver() method, which I'm running using the table() method, which I assume is async... I then yield the result which should be the contents contained in the rp_html table from the driver method. When I hit the post method, the script runs but it's still blocking my thread. What I'm I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Function `driver` is synchronous, blocking. Adding `coroutine` does not make function async. Check out http://blog.trukhanov.net/Running-synchronous-code-on-tornado-asynchronously/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `driver` function is blocking. It blocks because you're using `mongo` lib and `logging` module, which are synchronous. So, when you call

```
  sites = list(db.sites.find())
```

or

```
  logging.info('retrieving data for {0}'.format(date))
```

your loop actually is blocked waiting for the response.

So, `logging`. There is a built-in logging in `tornado` (see [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/log.html)), you need only to set your custom logging function in app settings, but it's also blocking. You may try using queues, e.g. logs are put into some queue, then some worker (async) puts them into stdout: every `ioloop` iteration the worker will start ([this way](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html?highlight=add_callback#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback)) and flush everything.

For `mongo` non-blocking stuff use for example `motor` library, like this:

```
    from motor.motor_tornado import MotorClient
    db = MotorClient().db

    cursor = db.sites.find()
    for document in (yield cursor.to_list(length=None)):
        # do something with the current record
```